# Differences between objects inheriting from an interface

Tags: c#

I have two objects based on an interface that I inject into a worker object.  The two objects do nothing other than format the parameters into XML that the worker object uses to pass to a web service.  I now have a change request that affects only one of the objects based on my interface.

I've found myself writing code based on checking the Concrete type of the object in the worker object.  I don't want to create specific code based on this check. I know I can move the code into the actual object but I don't really want to pollute that object with some complex code.  Any ideas?

At the moment I'm using a simple check in the worker object e.g

```
if (item.GetType() == typeof(Project)) {
 //do something
}
```

Comment: Create a new class that inherits the class that you don't want to pollute.

Comment: Well firstly writing allot of description is always wayyyy better then posting some minimal code. (sarcasm)

Comment: If you don't want to add the complex code inside a single code file, use `partial` keyword. Ideally the interface should have `Check()` and you put the domain checking code inside the object.

Comment: Its not about putting the code into the file.  The objects are more or less simple poco's and i would like to keep it that way

Comment: If you worker needs the information to do its work, then it should be added to the interface IMHO. Name it in relation to the worker though. ie don't call it IsProject, call it NeedsFropping or whatever.

Comment: How is putting a concrete implementation in a concrete object, polluting it? Based on your description, you are polluting the worker object.

Comment: Why not pattern matching like `if (item is  Project project) { project.DoXml(); }`